# React application what's the best way to get info from a COM port?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, windows, tsx

I'm doing a side project for someone and we decided on React.tsx .The application will need to take info from a boat( via a COM port) and use it to calculate some stuff. But i honestly do not know where to start. I did find a npm package(simply called serialport) but that's for js not tsx.

Answer (score 0):

In browser environments, you can work with COM Ports using the [Web Serial API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API), but you can notice that API is experimental (not working for all browsers). If you need something more solid, maybe a web application won't meet your needs.

The React choice itself does not change much for using the Serial API. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806607/using-web-serial-with-reactjs) to get more info about the specific API with React.